# How to edit/update existing component CSS in extjs with component ID as reference?

Tags: extjs

I have popup form component which has form header body footer. How can I update CSS of those HTML elements with the help of form container componentID.

I have tried these:

```
getComponent('stakeholderAddUserWindow').update({height: 1900});

getComponent('stakeholderAddUserWindow').addClass('newclass');

getComponent('stakeholderAddUserWindow').style: 'background-color: #5E99CC';

getComponent('stakeholderAddUserWindow').update({style: 'background-color: #5E99CC;'});
```

I have other doubt how to traverse from the container to inner child elements, here I have 3 child elements with classes x-header, x-body, x-footer. I want to apply CSS to the body.

```
<div class="x-window flex-window deploymentPlanWindow x-layer x-
window-default x-border-box" id="stakeholderAddUserWindow-1502" 
componentid="stakeholderAddUserWindow-1502">

  <div class="x-window-header x-header"id="stakeholderAddUserWindow-
  1502_header">header</div>

  <div class="x-window-body x-body"id="stakeholderAddUserWindow-
  1502_body">body</div>

  <div class="x-window-footer x-footer"id="stakeholderAddUserWindow-
  1502_footer">footer</div>

</div>

Ext.get(Ext.query('.x-window > .x-window-header')).setStyle('background', 'blue');
```

Above one not working

Comment: you mean apply on all child elements?

Comment: I want to increase the height of the div with x-body as class only and CSS for footer as bottom:0px

Comment: so use `Ext.query` to get the `DOM` and then `Ext.get` to get the element `Ext.get(Ext.query(YOUR-QUERY)).setStyle({height: 437})`

Comment: what is     (YOUR-QUERY) here I mean hot to select child dive from parent div

Comment: Ext.get(Ext.query('.x-window .x-window-header')).setStyle('color', 'red');

Comment: Ext.get(Ext.query('.x-window .x-window-header')).setStyle('color', 'red'); its not working

Comment: `Ext.get(Ext.query('.x-window .x-window-header')).setStyle('color', 'red');`  is working

Answer (score 1):

For editing styles use 'setStyle' function on `components` or `elements`

And for adding and removing classes use `addCls` and `removeCls` functions

```
getComponent('stakeholderAddUserWindow').setStyle('height', '437px');
```

Comment: Thanks @Hesam Faridmehr, I have other doubt how to traverse from the container to inner child elements, here I have 3 child elements with classes x-header, x-body, x-footer. I want to apply CSS to the body.

Comment: Edited above question, please check